# How to customize a button in tableviewcell?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uitableview, cgrectmake

I'm developing a iOS App and i am using Xcode 6.

I created 5 button in tableview cell programatically.i want to customize only a single button at a time.That means when i click a button it must enlarge and other buttons will keep the default size.

Now the problem is when i click a button,it will enlarge and if i click another button,it too enlarge.But i want to keep the remaining buttons in the default size that i have entered in CGRect Function.

Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

{



    UITableViewCell *cell;

    UIButton *b2,*b1;



}

//@property(strong,nonatomic)UIButton *b3,*b4,*b5;

//@property(strong,nonatomic)UIButton *b1,*b2;



@end



@implementation ViewController
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 5;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton  *b1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

  b1.frame=CGRectMake(13.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);

 [b1 setTag:1];

   [b1 addTarget:self action:@selector(modify:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[b1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

  [b1 setTitle:@"Blue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBButton *b2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  b2.frame=CGRectMake(73.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);
 [b2 setTag:2];
 [b2 addTarget:self action:@selector(modify1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [b2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[b2 setTitle:@"red" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  UIButton  *b3=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  b3.frame=CGRectMake(133.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);
  [b3 setTag:3];
 [b3 addTarget:self action:@selector(modify2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [b3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
  [b3 setTitle:@"Green" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 UIButton *b4=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 b4.frame=CGRectMake(193.0, 40.0,40.0, 40.0);
 [b4 setTag:4];
 [b4 addTarget:self action:@selector(modify3:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [b4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  [b4 setTitle:@"Black" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 UIButton *b5=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 b5.frame=CGRectMake(253.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);
 [b5 setTag:5];
 [b5 addTarget:self action:@selector(modify4:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [b5 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[b5 setTitle:@"Orange" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     [cell addSubview:b1];

     [cell addSubview:b2];

     [cell addSubview:b3];

     [cell addSubview:b4];

     [cell addSubview:b5];

 return cell;

 }

-(void)modify:(UIButton *)btn

{
 if (btn.tag==1) {
    btn.frame=CGRectMake(13.0, 40.0, 60.0, 60.0);
 }
 if (btn.tag!=1)
      {
   btn.frame=CGRectMake(73.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);
 btn.frame=CGRectMake(133.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(193.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);
       btn.frame=CGRectMake(253.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    }
}
-(void)modify1:(UIButton *)btn1
{

 if (btn1.tag==2) {

    btn1.frame=CGRectMake(73.0, 40.0, 60.0, 60.0);
 if (btn1.tag==1) {
btn1.frame=CGRectMake(13.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);
  }
}
-(void)modify2:(UIButton *)btn2
{
 if (btn2.tag==3) {
 btn2.frame=CGRectMake(133.0, 40.0, 60.0, 60.0);

    }
}
-(void)modify3:(UIButton *)btn3
{
if (btn3.tag==4) {
  btn3.frame=CGRectMake(193.0, 40.0, 60.0, 60.0);
  if (btn3.tag==3) {
      btn3.frame=CGRectMake(133.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    }

    if (btn3.tag==2) {
     btn3.frame=CGRectMake(73.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);

     }

     if (btn3.tag==1) {
       btn3.frame=CGRectMake(13.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);
   }

     if (btn3.tag==5) {
    btn3.frame=CGRectMake(253.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);

     }

 }

}

-(void)modify4:(UIButton *)btn4

{
 if (btn4.tag==5) {
    btn4.frame=CGRectMake(253.0, 40.0, 60.0, 60.0);
   if (btn4.tag==4) {
      btn4.frame=CGRectMake(193.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);

        }

    if (btn4.tag==3) {

            btn4.frame=CGRectMake(133.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);

        }

       if (btn4.tag==2) {
       btn4.frame=CGRectMake(73.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);

        }

       if (btn4.tag==1) {
       btn4.frame=CGRectMake(13.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0);
     }

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn4 addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn5 addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    btn1.tag=1;
    btn2.tag=2;
    btn3.tag=3;
    btn4.tag=4;
    btn5.tag=5;

-(IBAction)increaseAction:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    //Here perform the desired operation

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this lot of stuff do the following changes:
In the below method:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
         static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
         UITableViewCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
            UILabel *lblFirst=nil;
            UILabel *lblSecond=nil;

            UITableViewCellStyle style =UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle;
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
                //Account
                lblFirst = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(CGRectMake(0, 0, 130,
                                                                                 iRowHeight),10,2)] ;
                lblFirst.tag=1;

                [self labelCommonSettingsLeftAlign:lblFirst];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:lblFirst];
                //----------------------------------------
                //name
                lblSecond =  [[UILabel  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(CGRectMake(131, 0, 130,
                                                                                    iRowHeight),10,2)] ;
                lblSecond.tag=2;

                [self labelCommonSettingsLeftAlign:lblSecond];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:lblSecond];


                [lblFirst release];
                lblFirst=nil;
                [lblSecond release];
                lblSecond=nil;
            }

            lblFirst = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
            lblSecond = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];



      /*//Here u can check the condition of selected tag and indexpath.row.
       for e.g if(selectedTag==indexpath.row)
       {
             //change button size to New Size
        }
       else 
        {
              //change button size to Old Size
        }*/
   return cell;
}
```

Now in the above code I have added the Two labels on the cell. Instead of that U can add the Buttons on the cell.
Now Whenever you tap on the button then you will get the button tag. And by checking the `tag value` and cell `indexpath.row` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  u can change the button frame of selected button and other buttons. To do this u need to call the table view `reloadData` function. make sure the selectedIndex is initialized to -1.

Comment: i cannot getting right value of indexpath in button methods.

Comment: In button method u have to set the selected index and call the relaodData function.

Comment: The problem is the i cannot access the other buttons using indexpath or any other method in Button Action.cellForAtIndexPath i getting all the values.

Comment: i am not getting the correct value of selected index.In NSLog it displays null

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help you get correct index

```
    -(void)modify4:(UIButton *)sender {
         GPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
         NSIndexPath *currentPhotoIndexPath = [self.tableView  indexPathForItemAtPoint:buttonPosition];
           .....
    }
```